# wordpress css background color in a specific page only

Tags: colors, background

I am editing a site in wordpress acting on custom css. I would need to have a black background on the main page where all the products are displayed and keep the white background inside the product sheet.

currently I have entered this code:

```
.site-container {
  position:relative;
  background:black;
}
```

this code worked in the main product grid, now the background is black, the problem is that it also changed the background of the single product page. how do i exclude the command to make it stay only on the product grid?
or alternatively which code should I enter to make the product sheet background white?
(the site I'm working on is not online yet)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add the background property to the page ID class for the page you want to change the background.

So for example your page ID is 6:

```
.page-id-6 {
  background:black;
}
```

This css is only applied to the page with the ID 6.

You can find the id with the dev tools of your browser, just have a look at the classes of the HTML Body.

Comment: Try this:

`.page-id-6 {
  background:black!important;
}`

Comment: thanks for the help, it doesn't work, probably because it is connected to woocommerce and doesn't have a simple wp page